# How do I access my model class inside my module rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here is my module in lib/p_table.rb:

```
class PTable
    .
    .
    .
    def convertElmentToMass(el)
         @el = Element.find_by_symbol(el)
    end
end
```

Here is my model if it is any relevance in my app/models/element.rb

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

For some reason when I try to test my convertElementToMass function it says `uninitialized constant PTable::Element`. It is weird because I should be able to call my model class anywhere right?

Here is my rspec in lib/controllers/module_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'
require 'p_table'

describe PTable do
    class DummyClass
    end 

    before(:all) do
        @dummy = DummyClass.new
        @dummy.extend PTable
    end

    describe "testf" do
        it "saves the world" do
            expect(@dummy.(["Na", '2'])).to eq(2.34)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How are you testing `convertElementToMass()`? Where are you calling it from?

Comment: I updated it. I use rspec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `::Element` instead of `Element` only and it will work.

By default, the Rails autoloader will try to find the class internally at the module, by including the `::` you let the system know you want the `Element` class at the root module.